# How to solve reportMissingImports from discord in vscode

Tags: python-3.10

My Python is 3.10.0 64-bit and I just install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools to solve problem about wheel.Now I can install discord package but when I building a discord bot I got this [this is my problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs8z4.png)